# How to prove that a partial derivative of a combined function exists?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

For one of my homework assignments the following function is given:
$h: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ with the following properties:

1. The domain of $h$ is $\mathbb{R}^3$
2. All of its second order partial derivatives and below exist and have the same domain as $h$

Now they have given me another function $H: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ which is defined like this: $H(x,y) = h(e^{xy}, x^2 - y^2, 3)$.

Now they want me to prove that $\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}$ exists and is defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$

I started thinking about the Chain Rule for multi-variable functions and I stumbled upon the fact that all of $h$'s partial derivatives must be continuous. But how do I prove this? I'm obviously missing some crucial, maybe trivial, fact. Could anybody give me some hints as to how I should start proving this?

Comment: The chain rule does not require the partial derivatives of $h$ to be continuous. Just that they exist. (And FYI - "proof" is a noun, never a verb in mathematics.)

Comment: Thank you for correcting the mistake. My textbook says quite the opposite, but the need for continuity wasn't mentioned in the lecture either and i can't find it on the internet as well. The assignment is now a lot easier. Thanks again!